# IndexError: tuple index out of range (PostgresSQL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, tuples

I'm learning **PostgresSQL** as a newbie I got stuck at this error called '*IndexError: tuple index out of range*'
I can't understand what I did wrong in this. Here is the full error:

```
PS C:\Users\ketan\Documents\Python> & C:/Users/ketan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/ketan/Documents/Python/error.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ketan\Documents\Python\error.py", line 10, in <module>
    update_table(20,16,'Apple')
  File "c:\Users\ketan\Documents\Python\error.py", line 6, in update_table
    cur.execute("UPDATE store SET quantity=%s, price=%s, item=%s WHERE item=%s",(quantity,price,item))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Here is the code I Executed:

```
import psycopg2

    def update_table(quantity,price,item):
        conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres' password='(Your-own-password-please)' host='localhost' port='5432'")
        cur=conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE store SET quantity=%s, price=%s, item=%s WHERE item=%s",(quantity,price,item))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    
    update_table(20,16,'Apple')
```

Please give me some solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are couple of issues :

1. your query expects 4 parameters and you are passing 3 (parameter for initializing 'item'
2. you are passing numbers , so you should use %d
3. for string parameter you should surround them with quotes.

```
cur.execute("UPDATE store SET quantity=%d, price=%d, item='%s' WHERE item='%s'",(quantity,price,item,item))
```

on the second thought , you even don't need to update item when you are searching by item , it doesn't make sense:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE store SET quantity=%d, price=%d WHERE item='%s'",(quantity,price,item))
```

Comment: Dont change function definition , don’t add another item as input parameter , just pass it to the query twice . Notice I just changed the query line

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. The problem is solved after some tweaks in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The index referred to is the index into a python structure, not a database index.  You have 4 `%s` place holders, but only feed it 3 values.